# Email patterns with primefaces

Tags: validation, email, jsf-2, primefaces, design-patterns

I think my problem is simple enough, but I can't seem to overcome it.
I'm using an input text for emails like this:

```
<h:outputLabel value="Mail:" for="mail" />
                 <p:inputText id="mail" value="#{UtilisateurBean.mail}"
                    title="Mail" validator="#{UtilisateursValidate.email}"
                    validatorMessage="ecrivez un mail valide">
                    <f:validateRegex
                       pattern="[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]@[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]" />
                    <f:validateLength minimum="2" />
```

The problem is that it doesn't support the dot character before the @ like nouraty.n@mail.com (which is usually the case for gmail). I tried stuff like:

`pattern="[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]@[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]"`

`pattern="[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9\._%-]@[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]"`

But no luck.
Can anyone suggest a solution for this issue?

Comment: <f:validateRegex pattern="[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]@[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]" /> works for me just fine (tested with nouraty.n@mail.com)

Comment: :s then could their be any other reason why nouraty@mail.com works but not  nouraty.n@mail.com?? even thow i doubt it!

Comment: What exactly is `validator="#{UtilisateursValidate.email}"` doing? Isn't it performing the validation against an invalid pattern? What if you remove that attribute? Note that validators are executed in the order as they're declared on the component, starting with the `validator` attribute as the first one.

Comment: that's me trying  somthing and forgot to take it off, i've been looking at it so much that i'm not seing the obvious. than you so much it was actualy another validation in a class that was taking controle.

Comment: Okay. I reposted it as an answer so that you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSF validators are executed in the order as they're declared on the component, starting with the one in the component's `validator` attribute, if any. You've there a `validator="#{UtilisateursValidate.email}"`. If it's validating against a different (and wrong) pattern and throwing a `ValidatorException`, then you'll still keep seeing the validator message.

Removing or fixing that validator should solve your problem.